# how to assign different markers to the max value found in each column in the plot

Tags: matplotlib

How would I assign markers of different symbols to each of the max values found in each curve?, Ie, 4 different markers showing the max value in each curve.

Here is my attempt

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
maxValues=df.max()
m=['o', '.', ',', 'x',]
df.plot()
plt.plot(maxValues, marker=m)
```

In my real df, the number of columns will vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. Note that I used a `V` instead of `,` as the comma (pixel) wasn't showing up clearly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df.plot(figsize=(20,5))
mrk = pd.DataFrame({'A': [df[['A']].idxmax()[0], df['A'].max(), 'o'],
                   'B': [df[['B']].idxmax()[0], df['B'].max(), '.'],
                   'C': [df[['C']].idxmax()[0], df['C'].max(), 'v'],
                   'D': [df[['D']].idxmax()[0], df['D'].max(), 'x']})
for col in range(len(mrk.columns)):
    plt.plot(mrk.iloc[0,col], mrk.iloc[1, col], marker=mrk.iloc[2, col], markersize=20)
```

I created the `mrk` dataframe manually as it was small, but you can use loops to go through the various columns in your real data. The graph looks like this. Adjust markersize to increase/decrease size of the markers.

[image: Output graph]

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks